# Random Forest - or other Machine Learning - with Different number of features

Tags: python-2.7, intersection, random-forest

I am trying to compare a list of numbers with another list of lists to see how many of them match fairly closely.   However each of my data sets could have a different length.

As an example, if I had a list of time spent studying, student 1 might have

```
1 -  [ 10.0,  25.0,  15.7,  45.0]
```

and be compared against the list of other students that were

```
2   -   [  9.0,   30.0,  3.0]

3   -   [  26.0,  44.0]

4   -   [  5.0,   70.0,  90.0,  100.0]

5   -   [ 9.0,  27.0,  13.7,  42.0,  56.0,  60.0,  75.0]
```

I would want the comparison to score highly comparing study 1 vs 5 because there were 4 times that all scored well, even though student 5 had extra times that student 1 didn't have,   and I would want it to score fairly well for student 1 vs 3  because some of the numbers matched closely, even though some did not

I am just getting started with machine learning, and am only passingly familiar with Random Forests.    Can you use them to do this type of comparison or do they have to have the same parameters ?    Can you suggest a different method ?

Effectively what I am looking for is an intersection of sets, with loose parameters.    I would like to implement this in python

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Normalization

Start by first normalizing the data in the range 0 to 1. This can be done using the following formula.

```
Norm(e) = (e - Emin) / (Emax - Emin)
```

for each value e in each vector. (I don't know how to put math symbols in here or I would.)

So for example the first vector would become...

```
1 -  [ 10.0,  25.0,  15.7,  45.0]

Norm(10.0) = (10.0 - 10.0) / (45.0 - 10.0) = 0.0

1 -  [ 0.0,  25.0, 15.7,  45.0]

Norm(25.0) = (25.0 - 10.0) / 35.0 = 15/35 = 3/7 ~= 0.42857142

1 -  [ 0.0,  0.42857142, 15.7,  45.0]
```

...

```
1 -  [ 0.0,  0.42857142, 0.30571428,  1.0]
```

Do this for every vector and then calculate the mean squared error of each pair
adding/removing necessary 0's. This should give you a pretty good scoring mechanism. If you need to you can also split a 1.0 into 2 0.5 entries.

#### Mean squared error

You can calculate the mean squared error using the following equation.
Where n is the number of elements in each vector and Y hat, Y are the two vectors which you are looking to get the MSE for.

[image: Mean squared error]

in code the function would look something like...

```
public long getMSE(long[] v1, long[] v2) {
    long returnValue = 0.0L;
    for (int i = 0; i < v1.length; i++) {
        returnValue += Math.pow(v1[i] - v2[i], 2);
    }

    return (long) (returnValue / v1.length);
}
```